# Property 'forChild' does not exist on type 'typeof IonicModule'

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm using the ionic cli to generate the page using this command

```
ionic generate page login
ionic g page login
```

then i get this error in browser

```
Typescript Error
Property 'forChild' does not exist on type 'typeof IonicModule'.
E:/workspace/Ionic/myApp/src/pages/login/login.module.ts
imports: [
  IonicModule.forChild(Login),
],
```

also creating 4 items in login folder.

```
1.login.html
2.login.ts
3.login.module.ts
4.login.scss
```

any body can solve this.
here is login.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Login } from './login';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    Login,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicModule.forChild(Login),
  ],
  exports: [
    Login
  ]
})
export class LoginModule {}
```

if i remove this line , app works fine.

```
 IonicModule.forChild(Login),
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is

`IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)`.

Github link [here](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/src/index.ts#L481).

```
export class IonicModule {

/**
 * Set the root app component for you IonicModule
 * @param {any} appRoot The root AppComponent for this app.
 * @param {any} config Config Options for the app. Accepts any config property.
 * @param {any} deepLinkConfig Any configuration needed for the Ionic Deeplinker.
 */
 static forRoot(appRoot: any,  
                config: any = null, 
                deepLinkConfig: DeepLinkConfig = null): ModuleWithProviders {
```

For bootstrapping a single page you could try [IonicPageModule](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/src/index.ts#L581).

```
@NgModule({
   imports: [IonicModule],
   exports: [IonicModule]
})
export class IonicPageModule {

   static forChild(page: any): ModuleWithProviders {
```

Change your import to :

```
 imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(Login),
  ]
```

Update:

Relevant links:[IonicPage](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/IonicPage/),
[IonicPageModule](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/IonicPageModule/).

According to the [google docs](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1vGokwMXPQItZmTHZQbTO4qwj_SQymFhRS_nJmiH0K3w/edit) shared in [discussion here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-3-0-0-beta/84540/5) this is introduced in `ionic 3` for lazy loading of ionic pages.

Comment: why this new page is creating.before this was not in page folder?
even also not happening in my old project

Comment: what is your ionic version?

Comment: is we need to use this module,ts any where , or this is just for this folder ?

Comment: If you want for a particular component to have url use IonicPageModule.forChild() in your module.. if you are just bootstrapping your app use IonicModule.forRoot() in your module..

Comment: what exactly were you trying to do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140047/discussion-between-muhammad-nadeem-and-suraj).

Comment: This one helped me `https://docs.google.com/document/d/1vGokwMXPQItZmTHZQbTO4qwj_SQymFhRS_nJmiH0K3w/edit# it was introduced for lazy loading.. I think someone made a typo.. should be IonicPageModule instead of IonicModule..`

Comment: @Stephen glad it helped :)