# What is component level Module in Ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I just scaffolded an Ionic2 starter and generated a page using -

```
ionic generate page LogIn
```

What I see is, in the log-in folder a new file as `log-in.module.ts` and it has a line with a method named `forChild()` (see attached image)

[image]

The forChild() method is marked as Error in my VS Code editor.

My questions are:

1: What does this Module do ?

2: The Error in code does not allow me to correctly compile the app unless I comment that line out. How to solve this ?

Please help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43248635/property-forchild-does-not-exist-on-type-typeof-ionicmodule/43249252#43249252

Comment: does the answer clear it?

Comment: also https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/11082

Comment: @suraj Thank you very much for the reply. Its really neat and helped me a lot. Thanks again. I also up voted your answer on the link you shared.

Comment: no problem:)..glad it helped out